# Some number "and some"

Tags: phrase-usage, grammatical-number

I want to express an approximation of a share of a whole by using a fraction close to a known value, but, knowing that I have chosen a fraction that is smaller than the known value, I add "*and some*" to express that it is more than the fraction.

> "Of those in this category, one-third *and some* (34.9%) have this quality. Less than one-third (30.5%) have that quality."

I could say "*more* than one-third", I know.  In the rest of the document I have, several times;  I would want to use this to break up repetition.  Do I believe I have knowledge of this phrase because there are examples of this phrasing in literature, or am I thinking of the phrase "and *then* some" and subconsciously subtracting "*then*"?  In the end, is this a good use of the word "*some*"?

Comment: I don't recognise _and some_ in this use, and would only guess the intended meaning. I do recognise _and then some_ in this sense, but I would regard it as informal, and not appropriate to a document which quotes percentages to 1dp.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, and for the quick response too.  It's helpful.

Comment: "Just over a third" would be more idomatic.

Comment: You're quite right. The cited text is "non-standard" for ***X and then some*** ("somewhat more than X").

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wrote is perfectly correct, but it would take me rereading the sentence to understand it, because I'd first misread it as the "some" being 34.9% on top of the one third. I've always used "a little more than one third" in this case. You could also use "slightly more than one third".

Of course, that doesn't break up your repetition of "more" like you want. You could use "over" instead, to say "over one third", "a little over one third", "slightly over one third".

(I wouldn't use the hyphen myself in "one third", but wouldn't be surprised if some people did.)

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, and its immediacy.

Comment: @P.Coltharp you're welcome. As Colin brought up in his comment, different phrases are better for formal or informal writing. I wonder if most of my example phrases might be too informal for what you're writing.

Comment: But the rest of the document repeats "more than" and "over" ad nauseum, and my brain wants to revolt.  Since I can't revolt over the rest, maybe I can add this little bit.  Reading the text as it might read in the hypothetical document that I've imagined, I believe you would be very accustomed to the pattern of "*that* is more than *this* fraction (x.x%)", so you would not have misread it.  You would have, however, never read the sentence above because you closed the book five minutes ago and found something better to do...  Again, thanks.